# Выражение "мне вкусно"

Tags: грамотная-речь

Правильно ли говорить "мне вкусно"?

Answer (score 5):

Я цитатищу дам, огромнющую. Жутко развлекательную!

> **МНЕ ВКУСНО! КАК ГРУСТНО...**
>
> Явление, о котором мы поговорим сегодня, возникло где-то в середине
>   1990-х годов, и в первый раз я столкнулась с ним при прочтении
>   детективного романа. "Вкусно ли тебе?" — вопрошал герой героиню, а она
>   отвечала: "Да, мне вкусно".
>
> В соответствии с принципом парности случаев буквально через неделю
>   после исторического столкновения ко мне обратился приятель с просьбой
>   подтвердить его жене, что говорить "мне вкусно" — неправильно. Я
>   подтвердила, и она вроде бы даже поверила, но захотела узнать, почему
>   это неправильно. Вопрос застал врасплох. "Почему? — то мямлила, то
>   горячилась я. — Ну, как бы тебе сказать... Наверное, потому, что так
>   не говорят. Почему не говорят? Да не принято — и все! Что у тебя,
>   совсем языкового чутья нет? Хочешь казаться малограмотной — продолжай
>   в том же духе". Как ни странно, горячность часто бывает убедительнее,
>   чем логика, и мне поверили на слово.
>
> Прошло время, и вдруг случился обвал: выражение "мне вкусно" стало
>   звучать чуть ли не из каждого утюга, и к настоящему моменту этот
>   процесс начал приобретать масштаб стихийного бедствия. Стало ясно, что,
>   пока не поздно, надо побороться, но возник вопрос: а как? Пришлось
>   искать логику, и начала я с поисков академического правила. Найти его,
>   к сожалению, не удалось, и причина неудачи вполне ясна — в таком
>   правиле не было нужды потому, что еще совсем недавно не было и нужды
>   регулировать данный процесс: не делали такую ошибку. И вопрос этот
>   больше относится к культуре речи, чем к грамматике.
>
> Поэтому я призвала на помощь коллегу, вместе с которой мы, прикинув
>   так и эдак, пришли к следующему выводу. В конструкциях типа "мне
>   как-то" с местоимением "мне" употребляются так называемые
>   сказуемостные наречия (категория состояния), которые имеют значение
>   психического или физического состояния и используются в безличных
>   предложениях: "мне весело", "мне безразлично", "мне холодно" и пр. А
>   **слово "вкусно" — это не категория состояния, а типичное наречие, поскольку оно связано с конкретным предметом или действием и,
>   соответственно, не может использоваться в безличных предложениях.**
>   Например, "пирог вкусно пахнет", "икра — это вкусно", "в этом кафе
>   вкусно готовят". Последнее предложение, правда, — тоже глагольное
>   односоставное, но уже не безличное, а неопределенно-личное: всем
>   понятно, что готовит повар или тот, кто взял на себя его функции.
>   Позволю себе напомнить читателям, что такое категория состояния. Это
>   класс слов, которые обозначают — вы удивитесь! — состояние, обычно
>   отвечают на вопрос "каково?" (каково тебе? — мне холодно) и
>   используются, как правило, в качестве главного члена односоставного
>   предложения ("холодно" — сказуемое в безличном предложении, "мне" —
>   дополнение). Важно уметь отличать их от омонимичных им форм наречий и
>   кратких прилагательных. Посмотрим, чем может являться, например, слово
>   "тяжело" в разных предложениях. Он тяжело поднимался в гору — наречие.
>   Тяжело ты, мое сокровище — краткое прилагательное. На сердце у меня
>   тяжело — категория состояния.
>
> Для того чтобы относиться к категории состояния, слово должно как
>   минимум обозначать состояние: все равно какое, кого или чего —
>   человека, животного, природы, социальной установки. Это, например,
>   "можно", "страшно", "надо", "нельзя", "жарко", "слышно", "жаль",
>   "темно", "неохота", многие другие, и все они в качестве категории
>   состояния прекрасно сочетаются с местоимением "мне", равно как и с
>   "тебе", "ему" и так далее, сочетаются и с существительными. "Мне
>   неохота", "Сергею жарко", "ему не слышно", "человеку надо"... А с
>   какого это перепуга человеку вдруг может сделаться "вкусно"? Когда мы
>   говорим "да, очень вкусно", мы подразумеваем нечто, имеющее хороший
>   вкус, просто опускаем слово "это". То есть "вкусно" может являться
>   либо наречием, либо кратким прилагательным, но категорией состояния —
>   никогда.
>
> Мы чувствуем холод — нам холодно, мы чувствуем радость — нам радостно,
>   но "вкусно" — совсем из другой оперы: это слово не означает, что мы
>   ощущаем вкус, оно означает приятный вкус самой еды. Кстати,
>   употребляющиеся в нашей речи слова того же порядка, например "сладко"
>   и "горько", в переносном смысле могут относиться к категории
>   состояния: ему горько, всем несладко. Но это в переносном! Я думаю, ни
>   один упертый филолог не возразит против выражения "ей так вкусно
>   живется". И правильно сделает, поскольку мало того, что "вкусно" здесь
>   употреблено в переносном смысле, оно еще и является наречием, а не
>   категорией состояния.

Comment: >> *Мы чувствуем холод — нам холодно, мы чувствуем радость — нам радостно, но "вкусно" — совсем из другой оперы: это слово не означает, что мы ощущаем вкус, оно означает приятный вкус самой еды.*    Не понимаю, почему не означает... Мы именно и ощущаем приятный вкус еды... "[Мне] вкусно!" — так вполне мог сказать Чичиков, кушая поросенка.  Но цитата хороша, спасибо. ))

Answer (score 2):

Так можно сказать в редких случаях, например в противопоставление реплике "Невкусно": "А мне — вкусно!". **Вкус** при этом **относят к еде**, а не к абстрактному ощущению вкуса (не просто "мне вкусно", а "мне вкусно то, что я ем"). В обычных же случаях "мне" (это мои ощущения от этого блюда) если и подразумевается, то не произносится. Зачастую "вкусно" — это сложившееся мнение о вкусе блюда на основе личного опыта — тогда говорящий подразумевает, что упоминавшееся перед этим блюдо как бы "вкусно всем".

Answer (score 0):

Так говорить можно, но не нужно. Если утверждать, что говорить «мне вкусно» правильно, то можно прийти к правильности «мне лениво».

Ошибка в том (и она глобальна), что к правильному *вкусно* не добавляется правильное, в общем случае, *это*, а лепится излишнее *мне*. Либо говоришь о еде, указывая глазами, жестом: ***это вкусно***, или просто ***вкусно***, тогда понятно, что всё по вкусу. Ведь, говоря *вкусно*, очевидно, делятся своими и только своими ощущениями, не иначе. Лишние слова (я, мне, моё, мнение) в кругу ближних простительны, а в компании строгих нравов могут выйти боком. Вывод: хромают обе ноги, лексическая и этическая.

Comment: Не лениво, а лень. И сразу всё нормально: нашли слово категории состояния.

Comment: Лень тут причём, и что сразу нашли? Вот ещё «категории» на выбор: мне можно, мне тихо, мне сложно, мне лихо. Дальше прозой — мне горько, мне любопытно, мне странно, мне красиво, мне прекрасно, мне непохоже. Последний перл зафиксирован у Сергея Доренко.